# How to send Onesignal push notification to specific user in python flask or with segment?

Tags: python, onesignal, flask-restful

I am absolute new to Onesignal and having problem integrate it in pyFlask. My rest API sending push notification on react app on all device but now I want it to send a specific user of app. Can anyone please help me with the code? Is it possible to anyone help me with code to send specific user

```
from onesignal import OneSignal, SegmentNotification
client = OneSignal("key", "key")
notification_to_all_users = SegmentNotification(
contents={
    "en": "Hello from OneSignal-Notifications"
},
included_segments=[SegmentNotification.ALL]
)
client.send(notification_to_all_users)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import onesignal as onesignal_sdk

payload = {
    "included_segments": ["All"],
    "contents": {"en": "Lorem ipsum dolor amit falit matit", "ru": "Lorem ipsum dolor amit falit matit"},
    "android_gcm_sender_id": "XXXX",
    "android_channel_id":"XXXX",
    "android_group": "myapp",
    "android_group_message": "MYAPP",
    "large_icon": "https://img.onesignal.com/n/bf627043.png",
    "android_visibility": 1,
    "priority": 5,
    "android_sound":"notification",
    "headings": {"en": "New post"}
}

# create a onesignal client
onesignal_client = onesignal_sdk.Client(
    app_auth_key="XXXX",
    app_id="XXXX"
)

# create a notification
new_notification = onesignal_sdk.Notification(post_body=payload)

# Send notification
onesignal_response = onesignal_client.send_notification(new_notification)
```